# Uncaught ReferenceError: XXX is not defined at first, no errors when refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm having a unique problem (I have been looking for hours now)
I am trying to create an iFrame, using only javascript

Here's my code:

```
    <script>
    function resize(obj) {
        obj.style.width = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollWidth + 'px';
        obj.style.height = 0;
        obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
    }
    </script>

    <iframe  frameborder="0" width="1000" scrolling="no" onload="resize(this)" src="/myurl.url"></iframe>
```

When I reach the page for the first time, I get this error in the console log:

**Uncaught ReferenceError: resize is not defined
    at HTMLIFrameElement.onload**

So the iFrame isn't the right height...

But the weird part is when I **Reload/refresh (ctrl+R)** the page, **there is no errors**, and the iFrame is at the correct height ! Only the reload will work, If I press Back et click on the page again, I will get the errors. Once I press Reload, I can go back and forth with no errors !

I can't find any logic in that... Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: The variable name `resizeIframe` used in the error message suggests that you are using it somewhere in the code. The snipped you provided does not have it. So, there is no way we can guess what's the problem. Please, create fiddle that replicates the problem and share it here.

Comment: Terribly sorry, that was the old name: it's the same variable ! I've edited the question for less confusion, my bad.

Comment: Does your `resize` function defined in the `<script>` tag on your page, before `<iframe>` tag? Or, is it loaded from external file somewhere at the bottom of the page? Working fiddle link would be helpful.

Comment: It is in the same file, and inverting the positions (iframe before script) isn't effective...

Comment: @LoicBrisout Why don't you call the resize function from javascript itself. It will remove the problem of syncronization. The error is coming because javascript is sometimes not able to load before the HTML.

Comment: Do you mean, without the "onload" in the iframe?

Comment: I believe Ayush means as in `element.onload = resize;`